# Estilo por defecto de Edittext

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un `EditText` que se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer una acción en el `EditText` se cambia el background con el siguiente código:

```
edtCampo.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego se hace otra accion y se cambia nuevamente el background del `EditText` con el siguiente código:

```
edtCampo.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que en el EditText no me aparece la linea de abajo, que propiedad le debo dar???

Esta es la definicion del EditText en el layout

y el estilo:

fill_parent
wrap_content
?
android:attr/textAppearanceLarge
center_vertical|center_horizontal
10dp
10dp
@color/blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón por la que no aparece el subrayado es precisamente porque defines un color de fondo Transparente:

```
edtCampo.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Te sugiero añadir el siguiente color como `backgroundTint` y evitar usar el color transparente:

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
```

con esto tendrás el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Para realizar lo anterior programaticamente se realiza de esta manera, donde `#ffff4444` es el color correspondiente a `holo_red_light`:

```
myEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffff4444"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

para obtener como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo pongo transparente es por que antes estaba con un background de rojo, como hago entonces para pasar desde el background rojo a que quede como la primera imagen, esto se hace desde codigo JAVA

Comment: @SergioAndresMorenoHerrera quieres el fondo rojo y también el subrayado?

Comment: No, quiero el fondo transparente y el subrayado, como aparece en la imagen inicial

Comment: @SergioAndresMorenoHerrera ¿Tu imagen inicial no es como lo que muestro en mi imagen?

Comment: Si asi es, pero necesito llamar el 
   android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" en codigo java

Comment: @SergioAndresMorenoHerrera ok en código se realiza como lo actualicé en mi respuesta, pruebalo, saludos!

Comment: sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: Tu Activity extiende de AppCompatActivity? Agrega la definición del EditText en el Layout.

Comment: La actividad es un fragment, extends Fragment,

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar la "linea" inferior de color para que se note al usar el fondo rojo, debes cambiar los colores o color, en tu archivo `colors.xml`

Los tres colores que encontraras se generan automáticamente al crear un proyecto

```
 <color name="colorPrimary">#00695c</color>
 <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#004D40</color>
 <color name="colorAccent">#fffff</color> // aquí cambias el color que quieras, en tu caso yo usaria un negro para que resalte en ambos casos.
```

Comment: Lo pongo transparente es por que antes estaba con un background de rojo, como hago entonces para pasar desde el background rojo a que quede como la primera imagen, esto se hace desde codigo JAVA

Comment: Si quieres el color por defecto, sin fondo, solo le quita la linea de codigo donde asignaras el color @SergioAndresMorenoHerrera