# ¿Como hago para cambiar la actividad mediante AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android-studio

Este es el AndroidManifest la verdad no entiendo  mucho, es la primera vez que uso android studio, intente ubicar el "intent-filter" para el otro Mainactivity2 ya que quiero que sea lo que se vea cuando ingrese a la aplicacion, pero cuando hago eso simplemente no ejecuta la aplicacion y me sale como que la aplicación esta fallando, luego intente cambiarle el nombre a la activity,pero no funciono, no entiendo cual es el problema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppSDEMS"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppSDEMS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Hola nuevamente lisa, cuando veas que tienes un error es importante revisar el LogCat, el uso del LogCat al desarrollar aplicaciones android es esencial, puede ser la diferencia entre solucionar un problema en unos segundos o en días, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Configurar `Activity` que cargue inicialmente en la aplicación.**

Como lo comentas, **para que tu `Activity` sea lo primero que el usuario visualice al abrir la aplicación, la `Activity` debe tener definido el siguiente ["intent-filter"](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=es-419#Receiving)**:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Este ["intent-filter"](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=es-419#Receiving) debe ser configurado en solo una de las `Activity`, por lo tanto, debes definir de esta forma `MainActivity2` en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity2"
    android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Mientras que `MainActitiy` quedaría simplemente como

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppSDEMS">
</activity>
```

---

Si después de realizar la configuración anterior tienes algún error, posiblemente sería un problema en la `Activity`, aquí es importante revisar el `LogCat` para determinar el problema.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda! tendre mas en cuenta en revisar el LogCat, fue algo que se me paso por alto, ya que no entendia algunas herramientas de Android Studio, tengo otra duda que es diferente al tema del Manifest, es posible que se puedan cambiar los colores de los logos o iconos que hay en Android Studio?

Comment: @lisa si te refieres a images de recursos en tu proyecto, se pueden cambiar de colores aplicando un "tinte", por ejemplo puedes cambiar de color una imagen cargada en un ImageView usando setColorFilter(), incluso otro tipo de vistas, revisa : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22591/c%c3%b3mo-cambiar-color-a-progressbar/22678#22678  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/123109/estilo-por-defecto-de-edittext/123267#123267

Comment: la verdad me refiero a los activos vectoriales o "vector asset"  que se encuentran en el drawable ya que intente cambiarle del color negro para cambiarlo a blanco pero no logre hacerlo con uno de los iconos de mi barra de menú inferior y los otros si se cambiaron a blanco pero no tienen un blanco "fuerte" sino uno como medio mas transparente, nose si se puedan cambiar el color